# Turn a list structure into an accordion without altering the HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've found various jQuery scripts that partially work (they make parts of the text disappear but breaks on reappear, the parent and child disappear on click, etc.) but since I am very new to jQuery I can't really make my own fix or know how to make other scripts fit my problem.

How can I turn the following list structure into an accordion, where clicking on the header drops down the content?

Unfortunately, the web app this comes from does not allow altering the HTML, so only script and CSS solutions will work.

```
<ul>
    <li class="static selected">
        <a class="static selected menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-core-listMenu-selected ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="#">
            <span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">
                <span class="menu-item-text">Header1</span>
            </span>
        </a>
        <ul class="static">
            <li class="static">
                <a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="#">
                    <span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">
                        <span class="menu-item-text">Content1</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: as a general note `<dl>`, `<dt>`, and `<dd>` are structured more appropriately for an accordion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it using jQuery.

```js
$(function(){
    var hiddens = $('.menu-item + ul');         // Select all hiddens
    hiddens.each(function() {                   // Loop through all hiddens
        var hidden = $(this);                   // Save $(this) for later
        $(this).parent().click(function(e) {    // Catch the parent's click event
            hiddens.each(function(){            // Loop through all hiddens
                if(!$(this).is(hidden))         // Check if the current element 
                                                // is the one we want to toggle,
                    $(this).removeClass('show');// Hide it otherwise
            });
         hidden.toggleClass('show');         // Toggle the selected hidden
            e.stopPropagation();                // Stop this event from bubbling
        });
        $(this).click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();                // Stop this event from bubbling
        });
    });
    $(document).click(function(e) {             // Hide all shown hiddens.
        hiddens.filter('.show').removeClass('show');
    });
});
```

```css
.menu-item + ul {
    display: none;                          /* Hide all hiddens */
}
.menu-item + ul.show {
    display: block;                         /* Show only the current hidden */
}
```

```html
<!-- This HTML is used for the purposes of this demo, no changes made -->                                                                          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><ul><li class="static selected"><a class="static selected menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-core-listMenu-selected ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="#"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Header1</span></span></a><ul class="static"><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="#"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Content1</span></span></a></li></ul></li><li class="static selected"><a class="static selected menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-core-listMenu-selected ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="#"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Header1</span></span></a><ul class="static"><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="#"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Content1</span></span></a></li></ul></li><li class="static selected"><a class="static selected menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-core-listMenu-selected ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="#"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Header1</span></span></a><ul class="static"><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="#"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Content1</span></span></a></li></ul></li></ul>
```